# What is this type of format called? I need to do this in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

take in account this is my first time with LWC outside trailhead.

I need to create a board like this inside a lightning app page, but for admin tools that I have already developed.
[image]

I've searched in the library of recipes of salesforce and I did not find something like this.

is this called a board with cards?
Can anybody point me to a video or any content on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say the closest you can get in Salesforce's Lightning Design System is what they call a [tile](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tiles/), as used in the [App Launcher](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/app-launcher/) (but not as a modal window). There is a standard [tile component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tile/example). But sure, you can also use a [card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example).

Comment: Thanks Felix! Thats way closer to what I was looking for :)